# hooks during parsing of an expression

Tags: java, expression, mvel, jexl

I have a requirement to parse and evaluate user defined expressions.

The expressions are of the form "foo > 50 && bar < 60 && !(moo > 50))"

During parsing, there is a need to monitor value for foo > 50, bar < 60 and !(moo > 50) and generate events when conditions are met. The event evaluator will call the expression evaluation.

I looked at MVEL and JEXL, but unable to determine how to get hooks during parsing stage.

Other than bootstrapping a grammar with javacc or lex/yacc, any other options?

I am new to compiler/parser world (other than the class at grad school 20 years ago), please do advise if i am completely off track here.

thanks,
-kvh

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFLEX (http://jflex.de/) and/or ANTLR(http://www.antlr.org/) for this.

AFAIK ANTLR is new and powerful than JFLEX.

Comment: ANTLR involves same bootstrapping a grammar like javacc, right? I guess i am asking is there any baked in option in tools like MVEL, JEXEL that can be called during parser? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about MVEL,JEXEL.You can try some examples on JFLEX and ANTLR